# Is there any way add a columns with specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a data frame.
I would like to add column 'e' after checking below conditions.

1. if component of 'c' is in column 'a' AND component of 'd' is in column 'b' at same row , then component of e is OK
   else ""

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = {'a':[0,2,1,4], 'b':[4,5,1,7],'c':['1','2','3','6'], 'd':['1','4','2','9']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

The result I want to get is

```
A = {'a':[0,2,1,4], 'b':[4,5,1,7],'c':['1','2','3','6'], 'd':['1','4','2','9'], 'e':['OK','','','']}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `component of 'c' is in column 'a' `  ?

Answer (score 4):

You can merge `df` with itself on `['a', 'b']` on the left and `['c', 'd']` on the right. If index 'survives' the merge, then `e` should be `OK`:

```
df['e'] = np.where(
    df.index.isin(df.merge(df, left_on=['a', 'b'], right_on=['c', 'd']).index),
    'OK', '')

df
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d   e
0  0  4  1  1  OK
1  2  5  2  4    
2  1  1  3  2    
3  4  7  6  9
```

P.S. Before the merge, we need to convert `a` and `b` columns to `str` type (or `c` and `d` to numeric), so that we can compare `c` and `a`, and `d` and `b`:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, when I applied this code to a little bit complex csv file. I faced warning message as below  "You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation... "

Comment: @GihyunYi Yes, so the types of `a` and `b` must be the same as types of `c` and `d` respectively. In your case it looks like you have `int` and `float` columns that you're trying to merge on, so you can try converting the integer column to `float` before merging (with `.astype(float)`)